# Feedback Request

Tags: feedback

I have requested feedback from a business stake holder with whom I have worked closely for 8 months on an anchor program. I have sent an email to the stake holder copying my boss requesting constructive criticism. The business user who is usually remote was around at that time and I have requested a lunch meeting with her to which she obliged.

I have received a response from the business user after 10 hrs with her inputs.

On my next 1:1 with my boss he expressed his discontent on me directly reaching to the business stake holder requesting feedback. He said that it was his responsibility to request feedback. In addition, he said that he saw both us during lunch which makes him feel that's the reason why the feedback is sugar coated.

I couldn't agree with him. However I would like to solicit feedback on this forum.

Comment: I'm afraid there is little we can do for you. If your boss says it's his job, then it's *his* job. If you want to convince him that another approach is better, make a list of pro and cons and talk to him.

Answer (score 3):

You made a mistake. You preempted the boss and probably cost him money. As a boss I get upset when people call meetings when it's not their place to, either my people or a clients people. Meetings cost me in either time or money, and if I deem it is needless, then I'm not happy. I have handed clients huge invoices for wasting my time with something that could have been settled via email and let them know why they're being billed which has at least once ended with one of their staff being disciplined.

For a staff member to set up a meeting which the boss has to attend without discussing it first with the boss is even worse.

So don't do it again.

Answer (score 3):

> On my next 1:1 with my boss he expressed his discontent on me directly
>   reaching to the business stake holder requesting feedback. He said
>   that it was his responsibility to request feedback. In addition, he
>   said that he saw both us during lunch which makes him feel that's the
>   reason why the feedback is sugar coated.
>
> I couldn't agree with him.

You have forgotten that your most important stakeholder is your boss.

If you are confused, you should talk to your boss and try to learn why he wants to be the one to request feedback, rather than have you do it. You might learn the business reasons why it makes sense.

And you might want to probe a bit to find out why he feels that the feedback might have been "sugar coated". Perhaps this has happened with others in the past (or perhaps even with you).

You don't have to agree with your boss. But you do risk being penalized if you don't go along with his directives, even if that's not the way you would prefer to do things.

And if you have strong philosophical disagreements with many of your boss' directives, then you might wish to find another job where you wouldn't have such restrictions.

Answer (score 2):

Your boss' concern is valid. Communication between dev leader and business stakeholder is a carefully curated, nuanced process that is both art and science. You cut him out of the loop on an important conversation with a business stakeholder. It puts him in an awkward position, and interferes with the trust and communication pattern he is trying to maintain. And he's (probably) right: if you had a conversation with her in person, she probably did sugarcoat a little on the parts regarding your performance.

In future you should respect your boss' wishes on this matter. Some bosses might not care, but many will. Respect that.